# Why Converting Regression to Ordinal Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, mathematical-statistics, ordinal-data

**Intro:**

Ordinal Regression/Classification is a classification where the labels have orders (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression)

**Question**:

Can you comment what are pros and cons if someone wants to solve a regression problem by ordinal regression? Why someone should or shouldn't do that?

**Why I am asking:**

I work on a regression problem with binned inputs. So, the cardinality of input values is a number like N and thus the cardinality of all output is n << N.

Answer (score 0):

If the dependent variable is ordinal, then ordinal regression is probably the most advantageous approach in many situations.  Disadvantages?

1. It is more complicated to do than a simple hypothesis test.
2. Your audience may not be familiar with it.
3. There are assumptions that should be considered (proportional odds assumption).